# My Acer Aspire 3 A315-56 laptop has no bluetooth and installing the drivers doesn't work

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bluetooth, acer-aspire

My Acer Aspire A315-56 laptop has no bluetooth and installing the drivers doesn't work. I mean the drivers listed on the Acer website. Reinstalling the I/O driver also doesn't work.

Regarding what recent changes happened on my laptop, Windows Update gave me a firmware update yesterday by Insyde.

I'm using Windows 10 20H2

[image: some devices in device manager]

Comment: You have a device not working with the USB section. Bluetooth seems to be OK. I do not know if there is a relation between the two. Acer support (Insyde) suggests a BIOS update. You might consider that. Be very certain you get the BIOS file for your specific machine model number.

Comment: Your support page>>>>https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support-product/8191?b=1

Comment: What is your Bluetooth device? If USB, it's probably the one listed as "Unknown USB Device (Device Descriptor Request Failed)", and you're then either missing a driver, or the device is defective.

Comment: I've solved the problem now. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the problem now. It was a software issue. I uninstalled Acer Quick Access from my computer, and now the bluetooth works. Maybe reinstalling it would have also worked.

PS. Using System Restore didn't work.